# How to make the Flutter app bar with gradient background

Tags: flutter, gradient, appbar

This question is being posted here as the related question here on stack overflow has only workarounds but no straight to the point approach.

Answer (score 13):

this can be achieved with the fallowing code

```
AppBar(
  flexibleSpace: Container(
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      colors: [Colors.cyan, Colors.yellow], stops: [0.5, 1.0],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

See the Pen 
  [bGVBVpz](https://codepen.io/iamyadunandan/pen/bGVBVpz) by yadunandan ([@iamyadunandan](https://codepen.io/iamyadunandan))
  on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: Excellent, this is beautiful, why does https://pub.dev/packages/gradient_app_bar exist? xD

Comment: This feature was introduced after the package, I guess

Answer (score 7):

**For a simple appbar with a gradient background and centered title,**

```
AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // hides default back button
      flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.topRight,
            colors: [
              Color(0xffB1097C),
              Color(0xff0947B1),
            ]),
      )),
      title: Text("WishList", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white)),
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
```

[image]

**For a more complex appbar with a gradient background and action icons**

```
AppBar(
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // hides default back button
  flexibleSpace: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
        end: Alignment.topRight,
        colors: [
          Color(0xffB1097C),
          Color(0xff0947B1),
        ]),
  )),
  title: Text("Welcome guest", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white)),
  actions: [
    IconButton(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset("enter svg path",height: 20.0, width: 20.0),
        onPressed: () {
          print("Icon 1 pressed");
        }),
    IconButton(
      icon: SvgPicture.asset("enter svg path", height: 20.0, width: 20.0),
      onPressed: () {
        print("Icon 2 pressed");
      },
    )
  ],
)
```

[image]